# Xamarin.Forms - Way To Create A Main Layout Template?

Tags: templates, layout, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In Xamarin.Forms (C# code, ***not*** XAML), is there a way to create a layout template that can be reused on multiple pages? For example, I want a persistent header and footer across my mobile app, but I don't want to have to include them on every page. Many software technologies (e.g. Jade, .NET MVC _Layout.cshtml file, etc.) allow creating a layout template that can be reused, and into which content can be "injected into". Does Xamarin.Forms have something like this?

Note: same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34193938/how-to-create-a-main-layout-template-in-xaml), but is there a way to do this in C# code?

Answer (score 2):

Xamarin Forms 2.1 introduced `ControlTemplate` and `TemplatedPage` :

http://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-page-templates/

> `Xamarin.Forms` control templates provide the ability to easily theme and re-theme application pages at runtime.
>
> To define a ControlTemplate at the application level, a class must be created that represents the ControlTemplate. The class should derive from the layout being used for the template, as shown in the following code example:

```
class TealTemplate : Grid
{
  public TealTemplate ()
  {
    ...
    var contentPresenter = new ContentPresenter ();
    Children.Add (contentPresenter, 0, 1);
    Grid.SetColumnSpan (contentPresenter, 2);
    ...
  }
}

class AquaTemplate : Grid
{
  ...
}
```

> The following code example shows a ContentPage applying the TealTemplate to the ContentView:

```
public class HomePageCS : ContentPage
{
  ...
  ControlTemplate tealTemplate = new ControlTemplate (typeof(TealTemplate));
  ControlTemplate aquaTemplate = new ControlTemplate (typeof(AquaTemplate));

 public HomePageCS ()
  {
    var button = new Button { Text = "Change Theme" };
    var contentView = new ContentView {
      Padding = new Thickness (0, 20, 0, 0),
      Content = new StackLayout {
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
        Children = {
          new Label { Text = "Welcome to the app!", HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center },
          button
        }
      },
      ControlTemplate = tealTemplate
    };
    ...
    Content = contentView;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally i'd go with [a templated view](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.TemplatedView/) in your case.

I'll share an example with you since this was poorly documented at the time it was released to nuget and most documentation you can find is sadly on blogs.

PCL:

```
public class ApplicationHeader : TemplatedView
{
    protected override void OnChildAdded(Element child)
    {
        base.OnChildAdded(child);
        SetInheritedBindingContext(child, BindingContext);
    }

    #region HomeButtonStyle

    public static BindableProperty HomeButtonStyleProperty = BindableProperty.Create<ApplicationHeader, Style>(d => d.HomeButtonStyle, default(Style));

    public Style HomeButtonStyle
    {
        get { return (Style) GetValue(HomeButtonStyleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HomeButtonStyleProperty, value); }
    }

    #endregion HomeButtonStyle

    #region HomeButtonCommand

    public static BindableProperty HomeButtonCommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create<ApplicationHeader, ICommand>(d => d.HomeButtonCommand, default(ICommand), defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWay);

    public ICommand HomeButtonCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand) GetValue(HomeButtonCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HomeButtonCommandProperty, value); }
    }

    #endregion HomeButtonCommand

    #region CommandAreaContent


    public static BindableProperty CommandAreaContentProperty = BindableProperty.Create<ApplicationHeader, View>(d => d.CommandAreaContent, default(View), defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWay);

    public View CommandAreaContent
    {
        get { return (View) GetValue(CommandAreaContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandAreaContentProperty, value); }
    }

    #endregion CommandAreaContent

    #region HeaderTextLine1

    public static BindableProperty HeaderTextLine1Property = BindableProperty.Create<ApplicationHeader, string>(d => d.HeaderTextLine1, default(string), defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWay);

    public string HeaderTextLine1
    {
        get { return (string) GetValue(HeaderTextLine1Property); }
        set { SetValue(HeaderTextLine1Property, value); }
    }

    #endregion HeaderTextLine1

    #region HeaderTextLine2

    public static BindableProperty HeaderTextLine2Property = BindableProperty.Create<ApplicationHeader, string>(d => d.HeaderTextLine2, default(string), defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWay);

    public string HeaderTextLine2
    {
        get { return (string) GetValue(HeaderTextLine2Property); }
        set { SetValue(HeaderTextLine2Property, value); }
    }

    #endregion HeaderTextLine2

    #region HeaderTapCommand

    public static BindableProperty HeaderTapCommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create<ApplicationHeader, ICommand>(d => d.HeaderTapCommand, default(ICommand), defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWay);

    public ICommand HeaderTapCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand) GetValue(HeaderTapCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HeaderTapCommandProperty, value); }
    }

    #endregion HeaderTapCommand
}
```

App.xaml

Keep in mind that currently resource declarations must be in order to avoid app.xaml exceptions.

```
                            <controls:EnhancedButton Padding="24,0,24,0" IsVisible="{TemplateBinding HomeButtonCommand, Converter={StaticResource NullToBoolConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static x:Boolean.TrueString}}" Style="{StaticResource ButtonThemedDark}" Grid.Column="0" Text="=" Command="{TemplateBinding HomeButtonCommand}"></controls:EnhancedButton>
                            <Grid Grid.Column="1" extensions:GestureExtensions.TapCommand="{TemplateBinding HeaderTapCommand}" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource ColorThemeAccent}">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="{TemplateBinding HeaderTextLine1}" Style="{StaticResource LabelShellHeaderLine1}" IsVisible="{TemplateBinding HeaderTextLine1, Converter={StaticResource NullToBoolConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static x:Boolean.TrueString}}"></Label>
                                <Label Grid.Row="2" Text="{TemplateBinding HeaderTextLine2}" Style="{StaticResource LabelShellHeaderLine2}" IsVisible="{TemplateBinding HeaderTextLine2, Converter={StaticResource NullToBoolConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static x:Boolean.TrueString}}"></Label>
                            </Grid>
                            <controls:EnhancedContentPresenter Grid.Column="2" Content="{TemplateBinding CommandAreaContent}"></controls:EnhancedContentPresenter>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```