# Keep Tooltip Open when Mouse Hover

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, xaml, tooltip

I created a ribbon in WPF using .NET 4.0 framework.  I am trying to make use of *ToolTipTitle*, *ToolTipDescription* and *ToolTipFooterDescription*.  Since my tooltips will have hyperlinks, how can I make it so that when the mouse hovers over the tooltip, the tooltip stays open?

```
<rib:RibbonMenuButton ToolTipTitle="Title" ToolTipDescription="My Description" ToolTipFooterDescription="My Footer With a Link">
```

A good example of this functionality is with Microsoft Excel.  When you hover over a ribbon button, an advanced tool tip will display to the user, and if the user hovers over the tooltip, it will remain open.  I am trying to mimic that functionality.

Comment: Hello, regarding other discussions about it, you will have to design your own `ToolTip`. You could start by using some `PopUp` UIElement. Or you may found some librairies with interactives `ToolTip`, but I don't know about it.

Comment: Interesting that Microsoft has this functionality though on their own products.  It really looks as if they are using their own native API.

Comment: This [post](http://www.hardcodet.net/2013/11/quick-and-dirty-but-nice-tooltips-revisited-and-interactive) can be a good point to start from.

Comment: If you find a simple answer to your own question, you can put it here. It would be interesting for everybody :)

Answer (score 0):

I've updated my answer, the below is a well tested solution to my problem and will mimic Microsoft Office's tooltip generation:

First, create the popup control:

```
<Popup x:Class="WPF.Tooltip" AllowsTransparency="True"
       x:Name="TT_Popup_Control"
       xmlns:WPF="clr-namespace:Project_Namespace.WPF"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Project_Namespace"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Sans Serif" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11" />
                <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" x:Key="WrappingStyle">
                <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Border BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="1,1,0,0">
            <Border 
                    BorderThickness="0,0,15,15" 
                    BorderBrush="Transparent"                
                    CornerRadius="0" 
                    Margin="0"
                 >
                <Border.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10" Opacity="0.8"  ShadowDepth="5" Direction="-40" RenderingBias="Quality" />
                </Border.Effect>
                <StackPanel Background="#efefef">
                    <Grid Margin="5,0,5,0">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <!-- Title -->
                        <TextBlock Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Title, ElementName=TT_Popup_Control}" />

                        <!-- Description -->
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
                            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Image, ElementName=TT_Popup_Control}" />
                        </TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
                            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Desc, ElementName=TT_Popup_Control}">
                                <ContentPresenter.Resources>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" BasedOn="{StaticResource WrappingStyle}"/>
                                </ContentPresenter.Resources>
                            </ContentPresenter>
                        </TextBlock>
                        <Separator Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="2"  />

                        <!-- Image -->
                        <TextBlock Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="3">
                            <Image Margin="0,0,10,0" Width="16" Source="pack://application:,,,/Path/To/Image/help_icon.png" />
                            <TextBlock Margin="0,-5,0,0">
                                <Hyperlink RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate" NavigateUri="{Binding Footer, ElementName=TT_Popup_Control}">Tell Me More</Hyperlink>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Popup>
```

Next, create the code behind for this control.  For those of you who want the C# equivalent, you can head [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34193938/how-to-create-a-main-layout-template-in-xaml).  This is where I got the reference for creating a control template.

```
Imports System.Windows
Namespace WPF
    Public Class Tooltip
        Public Shared ReadOnly TitleProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Title", GetType(Object), GetType(WPF.Tooltip), New PropertyMetadata(vbNull))
        Public Shared ReadOnly DescProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Desc", GetType(Object), GetType(WPF.Tooltip), New PropertyMetadata(vbNull))
        Public Shared ReadOnly FooterProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Footer", GetType(Object), GetType(WPF.Tooltip), New PropertyMetadata(vbNull))
        Public Shared ReadOnly ImageProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Image", GetType(Object), GetType(WPF.Tooltip), New PropertyMetadata(vbNull))

        Public Property Title As Object
            Get
                Return GetValue(TitleProperty)
            End Get
            Set(value As Object)
                SetValue(TitleProperty, value)
            End Set
        End Property
        Public Property Desc As Object
            Get
                Return GetValue(DescProperty)
            End Get
            Set(value As Object)
                SetValue(DescProperty, value)
            End Set
        End Property
        Public Property Footer As Object
            Get
                Return GetValue(FooterProperty)
            End Get
            Set(value As Object)
                SetValue(FooterProperty, value)
            End Set
        End Property
        Public Property Image As Object
            Get
                Return GetValue(ImageProperty)
            End Get
            Set(value As Object)
                SetValue(ImageProperty, value)
            End Set
        End Property

        Private Sub Hyperlink_RequestNavigate(sender As Object, e As Navigation.RequestNavigateEventArgs)
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(e.Uri.ToString())
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

The third step is to create the popup functionality, which is best done via styles.  I created my style as a resource dictionary (you can call it PopupStyle.xaml, but you can also embed your style directly within the popup xaml control markup:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Classic" 
    xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

<Style x:Key="TT_Popup" TargetType="Popup">
        <Setter Property="VerticalOffset" Value="20" />
        <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="500" />
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="50" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PlacementTarget.IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard x:Name="OpenPopupStoryBoard" >
                        <Storyboard>
                            <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen" FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
                                <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.00" Value="True"/>
                            </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    <PauseStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="OpenPopupStoryBoard"/>
                    <BeginStoryboard x:Name="ClosePopupStoryBoard">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen" FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
                                <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.35" Value="False"/>
                            </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PlacementTarget.IsMouseCaptured, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <PauseStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="OpenPopupStoryBoard"/>
                    <BeginStoryboard x:Name="CloseImmediatelyPopupStoryBoard" >
                        <Storyboard>
                            <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen" FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
                                <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="False"/>
                            </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PlacementTarget.IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="False">
                <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="CloseImmediatelyPopupStoryBoard" />
                </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
            </DataTrigger>

            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <PauseStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="ClosePopupStoryBoard" />
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                    <PauseStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="OpenPopupStoryBoard"/>
                    <ResumeStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="ClosePopupStoryBoard" />
                </Trigger.ExitActions>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And finally, you must call your newly created ToolTip control in your Xaml markup like so:

```
<UserControl xmlns:WPF="clr-namespace:Project_Namespace.WPF"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             >
     <UserControl.Resources>
          <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
               <ResourceDictionary Source="PopupStyle.xaml"/>
                    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
               </ResourceDictionary>
     </UserControl.Resources>
     <Grid>
          <Button x:Name="button_name" />

           <!-- Tooltips -->
          <WPF:Tooltip Style="{StaticResource TT_Popup}" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=button_name}">
               <WPF:Tooltip.Title>
                    Tooltip Title
               </WPF:Tooltip.Title>
               <WPF:Tooltip.Image>
                    <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Path/To/Image.png" />
               </WPF:Tooltip.Image>
               <WPF:Tooltip.Desc>
                    Your Description here
               </WPF:Tooltip.Desc>
               <WPF:Tooltip.Footer>
                    www.example.com
               </WPF:Tooltip.Footer>
          </WPF:Tooltip>
     </Grid>
</UserControl
```

So this may be a complicated way to achieve this functionality, however once implemented, these tooltips are much better than the default tooltips, especially if you require user interaction.