# Custom Tooltip (Popup) does not stay open when Ribbon Is Collapsed

Tags: wpf, xaml, popup, ribbon, ribbon-control

I created a custom tooltip that stays open when the mouse hovers over a button by using a popup.  My solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51371844/keep-tooltip-open-when-mouse-hover).  You can see the following attachment that displays the popup working correctly.  By the way, any mouse event will be triggered on the popup in this state, such as MouseEnter:

[image: Tooltip Stays Open when Mouse Hover]

For simplicity, hovering a mouse over the popup will trigger the MouseEnter event:

```
<Popup MouseEnter="TT_Popup_Control_MouseEnter"></Popup>
```

The issue is when the Child Ribbon Buttons collapse.  When I click on the collapsed Parent Ribbon Button to expand the Child Buttons, and hover over the Child Button, I get something like this:

[image: Tooltip Does Not Stay Open when Mouse Hover]

Again for simplicity, hovering a mouse over the popup will **no longer** trigger the MouseEnter event:

```
<Popup MouseEnter="TT_Popup_Control_MouseEnter"></Popup>
```

So when I hover over the popup, the popup no longer stays open in this state.  Since the popup mouse events are no longer triggered, I believe this is the issue, but I don't know why this is the issue.  Did I discover a bug in the .NET framework?  Or is there something I am missing here?

Comment: It seems like you don't using build in ToolTip, maybe just try to stylize ToolTip instead of writing new one, it will behaviour like any other tooltip in WPF, but with custom content

Comment: I want the ToolTip to be interactive (for example, hover over and keep the window open to allow a user to click a link).  I just don't see any way to achieve this functionality on the default ToolTip without any major coding required.